# SVN: platform dependent externals, is it possible?

Tags: svn

I have some code that I would like to build on both Windows and Linux platforms. The tooling to build is also in SVN, and is linked into the main repository using externals.

Currently the structure is:

```
Top -+- Tools -+- Linux (external)
     |         |
     |         +- Windows (external)
     |
     +- Other Directories
```

I could setup the system where I checkout the Windows and Linux tooling on both platforms, however I would prefer to only have the Linux tooling checked out on Linux and the Windows tooling only on Windows. 
Ideally I would have one external (called tools), where the Linux tooling will be checked out on Linux and the Windows tooling on Windows, just to keep the development environment identical on both platforms.

```
Top -+- Tools (external, pointing to Linux or Windows repo)
     |
     +- Other Directories
```

Is this possible? I tried to find a solution to this, but I have the impression that it is not possible, is this correct?

Regards,
    Johan

Comment: Subversion offers full control on checked out items but you'll probably have to write shell scripts so you don't need to type the complete command every time.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that SVN has this option, but you could emulate it with your HTTP server.

Let's say the structure of your repository is

```
Top -+- Linux
     |
     +- Windows
```

Then you could use the Redirect directive in Apache to redirect access to Top->Tools to either of the two, depending on the operating system from which the HTTP request came.

Best,
Guido

Comment: Unfortunately, SVN doesn't support redirects for things inside repositories.  The only way this would work is if you had two different repositories one for Linux and one for Windows and based on something you (UserAgent or IP) you could figure out the OS.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I like the Apache solution, however I do  not have access to the web server. I decided to use my makefile to do this: based on the platform I am running on I checkout the Linux or Windows repository.